# How Can I Eliminate Moiré With Blackmagic 2.5K?

Tags: video, video-quality

[image: Example of moiré I'm getting on the tie]

Just picked up Blackmagic camera. Shooting in 2.5K for a series of interviews and experiencing excessive moire throughout all subjects. There are no obnoxious patterns on anyone, so I'm wondering what I can do minimize this and/or cancel out in the future.

Is there something I can do in Blackmagic settings in camera or in post production to cancel this out?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to post a full size frame grab?  It's hard to clearly see what is happening with the scaled down image.  JPEG artifacts also makes it hard to identify, so a full quality full size frame grab would be helpful.